# Voice Dial Aliases?

Tags: contacts, voice-command, voice-recognition

So I frequently use the voice-activated dial feature, wherein you say aloud "Call Jeff" and it will locate "Jeff" in your contacts and dial him.  However, I have run into an issue which stems from the fact that I, and many of my family/friends, are of a minority origin, and therefore have names which do not really have a great English pronunciation.  My attempts to voice dial these contacts have met with nothing but frustration and failure;  I have no idea what the voice dialer would consider a match to those contacts.  Is there any way to 'alias' a contact, so that instead of saying "Call Apichatpong" (which will do naught but confuse the dialer) I can say "Call Uncle" or "Call Father-In-Law" or something to that effect?  I do NOT want to have to rename the contact;  the person's name is what it is, and I'd prefer to see it that way in the contacts.  I just need an additional way to refer to that contact for voice-dial purposes.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Nickname" field? There is also, if you expand the name while editing the contact, places for phonetic spellings of names. That might also help.

Comment: What voice dialer are you using, one special to your phone, or Google Voice commands?